# What kind of Ruby / Erb is allowed inside HAML's :javascript filter?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml

It seems that inside of HAML's `:javascript` filter, no Ruby code is
allowed, not even a comment.

So this is NOT allowed:

```
:javascript
  - 1.upto(10) do |i|

:javascript
  -# just a comment not to show to public
```

(somebody said there is not way to hide comment like that inside a
`:javascript` filter.  Is that true?

but it seems the only thing allowed is

```
:javascript
  $('#aDiv').html('#{a_ruby_variable}');
```

only this #{ } is allowed.  Nothing else that is Ruby is allowed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I said on your other question, filters are (almost) entirely parsed separately from Haml. The only exception to this is `#{}`: for filters that just transform static text (that is, text that doesn't interact with the Ruby environment at all, so most filters other than `:ruby` and `:erb`), Haml adds this as a handy way of adding a Ruby value.

If you're looking for more complex Ruby integration with your text, filters are not the place to go. They're meant to be handy, not the be-all end-all solution to, say, putting JS in your template.

Comment: interesting... maybe it is for speed...  so the %script tag allows for more Ruby inside...  couldn't there be a :javascript_ruby filter that allows for more Ruby expression inside?